# Java Find lowest value in 2d array of string

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an assignment in which I am using 2d array of string which contains student name, course/ subject and marks each student got in each course. I want to find the lowest value in each course e.g In Maths Student a got 78, Student b got 98, Student C got 55 and Student D got 81.

I want my program to check the array and find the lowest marks in the array which is 55.

Here is my program code I am working but it is not giving me exact results which I am expecting:

```
String[][] resultCard =  new String[][]{ 
            { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"},
            { "Maths", "78", "98","55","81","65" }, 
            { "Physics", "55", "65", "88", "80", "64"}, 
            { "Java", "73", "66", "69", "79", "79"},
            { "C#", "74", "78", "45", "73", "85"},
            { "Ethics", "80", "90", "60", "70", "80"}
        };

double intresultCard=0;
double resultCardAvg=0;
int highest = 0;
int temp=0;
int lowest=0;

for(row=1;row<2;row++){
    for(col=1;col<resultCard.length;col++){
        intresultCard += Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][col]);
        resultCardAvg=intresultCard/5;
    }
}

for(row=1;row<2;row++){
    for(col=1;col<resultCard.length-1;col++){
        temp = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][col]);
        if(highest<temp){
            highest=temp;
        }
    }
}

for(row=1;row<2;row++){
    for(col=1;col<resultCard.length-1;col++){
        temp = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][col]);
        lowest = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][col+1]);
        if(lowest>temp){
            lowest=temp;
        }           
        System.out.println("The marks in temp are "+temp+ " & marks in lowest are "+lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What value are you expecting, and what value is it giving you?

Comment: this is what a debugger is for...

Comment: What output is it giving you, exactly; this is important to know so that we can address the problem head on.

Comment: With just a quick skim, your `for` loops are useless - they start with `row` at `1`, and continue until `row` is less than `2`, which is... exactly once. :-)

Comment: Doesn't `Integer.parseInt()` need to be inside a try-catch?

Comment: @Yann4 No it doesn't, but it is recommendable in order to avoid confusing errors. . .

Comment: @Yann4 Nope, @Cartier1288 is right that it doesn't. Specifically, it doesn't because `NumberFormatException`, which can be thrown by `parseInt()`, extends `RuntimeException`. These exceptions do not require explicit catching. (They are *unchecked* exceptions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the `for` loop surrounding the first, second, and third parsing `for` loops: are only looping once, so it is unnecessary. Secondly why find the average, it has no relevance to the specific marks. The second parsing loop looks good (aside from only looping once), but why find the highest mark, if you are trying to find the lowest mark? 
Also you aren't scanning all rows, only one row; meaning you are only receiving the data from the first subject, rendering the program unable to find the lowest mark out of all the classes. . . 
You could do something like this:

```
String[][] resultCard =  new String[][]{ 
    { " ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"},
    { "Maths", "78", "98","55","81","65" }, 
    { "Physics", "55", "65", "88", "80", "64"}, 
    { "Java", "73", "66", "69", "79", "79"},
    { "C#", "74", "78", "45", "73", "85"},
    { "Ethics", "80", "90", "60", "70", "80"}
 };

 int lowest = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[1][1]), tempInt;
 for(int row = 1; row <= resultCard.length; row++)
    for(int s = 1; s < resultCard[0].length; s++) {
        tempInt = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][s]);
        if(lowest > tempInt) lowest = tempInt; 
    }

 System.out.println("The Lowest Mark Out of All Classes Is: " + lowest);
```

Or You Could Do This For Lowest Per Class:

```
for(int row = 1; row <= resultCard.length; row++) {
    lowest = resultCard[row][1];

    for(int s = 1; s < resultCard[0].length; s++) {
        tempInt = Integer.parseInt(resultCard[row][s]);
        if(lowest > tempInt) lowest = tempInt;
    }

    System.out.println("The Lowest Mark For " + resultCard[row][0] + " Is: " + lowest);
}
```

Hope this helps  :)

`EDIT`:

```
static String[][] resultCard;
int average(int collumn) {
    if(collumn > resultCard.length) return 0;

    int average;
    for(int i = 1; i < resultCard[collumn].length; i++)
       average += Integer.parseInt(resultCard[collumn][i]);
    return average / resultCard[collumn].length;
}
```

You could do the same for the other mark editing, as well. 

 You could call them like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
//. . .
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    System.out.println(average(s.nextInt()));
}catch(InputMismatchException e){System.out.println("Incorrect Form of Input. . .");}
```

I don't know your current Java level, so understandably the code listed above could be quite cryptic; if so, comment and I would be happy to explain further :)

Comment: Kindly accept my apologies for the confusion. Actually in my assignment we have given task that the program needs to show average, highest marks and lowest marks by all students in each course and that is why I have got first two loops in my code, (I should have deleted them before posting here in order to avoid confusion) if user presses 1 then the program should show marks by all students in Maths, 2 for Java from all students, 3 for Java and so on. That is why my first loop is looping only once.

Hope it clarifies my question and thanks everyone for your valuable responses.

Comment: @Newbie: Ok, thanks for the reply; I appreciate your thanks and willingness to admit your mistake. If I were you, I would remove the loop, because it is not really a loop, of it only loops once. Also, if you want to find the different scores, I would advise you make seperate methods for each, in order to call them, and avoid messy code, I have edited my code to adhere to your need. . . Also if I answered your question, can you mark it as such :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
        String[][] resultCard = new String[][] {
                { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" },
                { "Maths", "78", "98", "55", "81", "65" },
                { "Physics", "55", "65", "88", "80", "64" },
                { "Java", "73", "66", "69", "79", "79" },
                { "C#", "74", "78", "45", "73", "85" },
                { "Ethics", "80", "90", "60", "70", "80" } };

        for (int i = 1; i < resultCard.length; i++) {
            int lowestMarks = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 1; j < resultCard[i].length; j++) {
                lowestMarks = Math.min(lowestMarks,
                        Integer.parseInt(resultCard[i][j]));
            }
            System.out.println("Subject : " + resultCard[i][0]
                    + ", Lowest Marks : " + lowestMarks);
        }
```

Output :

```
Subject : Maths, Lowest Marks : 55
Subject : Physics, Lowest Marks : 55
Subject : Java, Lowest Marks : 66
Subject : C#, Lowest Marks : 45
Subject : Ethics, Lowest Marks : 60
```